# Order By Case multiple fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

The code below (and numerous codes like it) continues to return blanks.

Basically, if LaborCode = '01 - SC' then it should sort by JobSite, LaborCode, and Schedule (the exact date)

If it's NOT 01 - SC, it should sort by JobSite, LaborCode, and DayNo (the day of the week)

```
Select Distinct Agreements.AgrmntID, Agreements.Description, Agreements.Status,
  JobSites.SiteName, JobSites.Address2, JobSites.City, Customers.CustName,
  Customers.CompanyName, LaborCodeTypes.RepairCode As LaborCode, Schedule = Case
    LaborCodeTypes.RepairCode
    When '01 - SC' Then Left(Convert(varchar,AgreementSchedules.SchedDate,110),
    10) Else DateName(dw, AgreementSchedules.SchedDate)
  End, Employees1.EmpName As Vendor, Employees.EmpName As [Area Manager],
  DatePart(dw, AgreementSchedules.SchedDate) As DayNo
From Agreements Inner Join
  Customers On Agreements.CustID = Customers.CustID Inner Join
  AgreementSchedules On Agreements.AgrmntID = AgreementSchedules.AgrmntID
  Inner Join
  JobSites On Agreements.CustSiteID = JobSites.CustSiteID Left Outer Join
  LaborCodeTypes On AgreementSchedules.RepairID = LaborCodeTypes.RepairID
  Left Outer Join
  Employees On AgreementSchedules.FormanEmpID = Employees.EmployeeID Left Join
  WorkOrderSchedules On WorkOrderSchedules.ScheduleID =
    AgreementSchedules.ScheduleID And AgreementSchedules.ScheduleID =
    WorkOrderSchedules.ScheduleID Left Join
  WorkOrderScheduleTechs On WorkOrderSchedules.ScheduleID =
    WorkOrderScheduleTechs.ScheduleID Left Join
  Employees Employees1 On WorkOrderScheduleTechs.EmployeeID =
    Employees1.EmployeeID
Where Agreements.Status = 2 And LaborCodeTypes.RepairCode <> 'Vendor Bill' And
  Month(AgreementSchedules.SchedDate) = Month(GetDate())
Order By Case
    When [LaborCodeTypes.RepairCode] In ('01 - SC') Then JobSites.SiteName +
    LaborCodeTypes.RepairCode + Schedule
    Else JobSites.SiteName + LaborCodeTypes.RepairCode + DayNo End
```

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY JobSites.SiteName, 
         LaborCodeTypes.RepairCode, 
         CASE WHEN LaborCodeTypes.RepairCode IN ('01 - SC') THEN Schedule ELSE DayNo END
```

Comment: Was just about to say that order by fields should be separated by commas

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working... but I understand that it SHOULD... still returning nothing.

Comment: Does it return results when you remove the ORDER BY entirely?

Comment: Just make sure that DayNo can never exceed the range of datetime. :-)

Comment: @JamieS what do you mean "returning nothing"? Do you think the `ORDER BY` could change the number of rows in the result?

Comment: @JamieS I have a question, do you have any preference about the sorting between the 3rd field options? Should you or not convert DayNo to the nearest future date which will correspond to that day of week and compare that in order by?

Comment: @DylanSmith, Aaron Bertrand - when I remove the entire "Order By" statement, I get results... also, I get results when I remove Dylan's CASE statement and leave the Jobsites, LaborCodeTypes

Comment: @xception - '01 - SC' has a specific schedule whereas everything else is Sunday, Monday, etc, etc.

Comment: @JamieS sorry, but that doesn't make sense. `ORDER BY` is not a filter. Are you running this in Management Studio or in an application? Is it possible there is some error when you remove the `ORDER BY`, and `TRY/CATCH` in your app is hiding that from you?

Comment: @JamieS I get that, it's just that you can't really compare a day of week with a date with it making any sense, so I asked if converting the day of week to the nearest future date which happens to coincide with that day of week should be done.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm using an application and it's quite possible that it can't do CASE within Order By...  I recently couldn't do XML Path (which is the reason for the above code)

Comment: @xception I'm not sure why it has to change to a date. In one case he wants to order by absolute date, in the other he wants to order by DayNo (e.g. all Sundays first, then all Mondays, etc). There is no reason that can't be done (but essentially they both come down to sorting by numbers).

Comment: @xception Gotcha... unfortunately the people around here would prefer to see specific dates for 01 - SC and days of the week for the other services (it's a building maintenance company - landscaping, sweeping, etc, etc).  They're weird, but nice.

Comment: @JamieS why don't you have your app call a stored procedure? You shouldn't limit yourself only to the T-SQL your app understands. Especially if you expect solutions from people here, who have no idea that you're using an app or what limitations it might have. Also if the app is returning an exception (never mind that the problem is in the app!), that's a much more powerful piece of information than telling us it returns no results.

Comment: considering the following 20-Sept-2012, Friday, 22-Sept-2012 should these be in the stated order or Friday first and than the rest - because the next Friday happens to be between those dates, I don't have any idea what he's trying to do so I thought this might be the case? To be even more clear, I didn't mean changing the actual field just it's interpretation while ordering In case he's displaying these as they are fetched in a single place.

Comment: @AaronBertrand ...because I don't know what that is or how to do it :(   Could you point me in a helpful direction perchance??

Comment: A `CASE` can only return a single data type.  If `Schedule` and `DayNo` are different data types, then you need to `CAST` or `CONVERT` them to something common, e.g. a `VARCHAR(64)`, that will sort properly.

Comment: I see this answer was accepted, but I think @HABO is absolutely correct - the current code here will lead to a conversion error in some scenarios.

Comment: @HABO - I changed DayNo to the following, but it still doesn't work: `Convert(varchar(5),DatePart(dw,AgreementSchedules.SchedDate)) As DayNo` ... is that wrong or is it safe to say it's the application??

Comment: What are the data types of `Schedule` and `DayNo`?  If they are character data then are they already formatted in a particular way?

Comment: @HABO they're both aliases created in the SELECT list. One's a string representation of a date, the other is a number representing the weekday.

Comment: I would convert `DayNo` to be a `VarChar(10)` to match `Schedule`.  FWIW, if I was sorting by a date I would choose a conversion format like 112 or 126 (to include the time), rather than 110, so that the sort order would make more sense.  (112 would return 8 characters, not 10.)

Comment: @HABO agreed about the style, but all the rows are within a single month in this case, so the style doesn't really matter. Month and year will be the same for every single row. Well, at least, I assume that is the intention.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, in SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Agreements_GetList
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT DISTINCT
    a.AgrmntID, 
    a.Description, 
    a.Status,
    js.SiteName, 
    js.Address2, 
    js.City, 
    c.CustName,
    c.CompanyName, 
    LaborCode = lct.RepairCode, 
    Schedule = CASE lct.RepairCode 
      WHEN '01 - SC' THEN CONVERT(CHAR(10), aSch.SchedDate, 110)
      --------------------^^^ much better than LEFT and not specifying length
      ELSE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, aSch.SchedDate) END, 
  Vendor = e2.EmpName, 
  [Area Manager] = e1.EmpName,
  DayNo = CONVERT(CHAR(1), DATEPART(WEEKDAY, aSch.SchedDate))
  --------^^^ this convert is important
FROM dbo.Agreements AS a 
INNER JOIN dbo.Customers AS c 
  ON a.CustID = c.CustID 
INNER JOIN dbo.AgreementSchedules AS aSch 
  ON a.AgrmntID = aSch.AgrmntID
INNER JOIN dbo.JobSites AS js 
  ON a.CustSiteID = js.CustSiteID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.LaborCodeTypes AS lct 
  ON aSch.RepairID = lct.RepairID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Employees AS e1 
  ON aSch.FormanEmpID = e1.EmployeeID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.WorkOrderSchedules AS w
  ON w.ScheduleID = aSch.ScheduleID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.WorkOrderScheduleTechs AS wt
  ON w.ScheduleID = wt.ScheduleID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Employees AS e2
  ON wt.EmployeeID = e2.EmployeeID
WHERE 
  a.Status = 2 
  AND lct.RepairCode <> 'Vendor Bill' 
  AND aSch.SchedDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, 0, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()))
  AND aSch.SchedDate < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()))
ORDER BY 
  js.SiteName,
  lct.RepairCode,
  CASE WHEN lct.RepairCode = '01 - SC'
    THEN js.SiteName ELSE DayNo END;
END
GO
```

Now I have absolutely no knowledge of your application, so you will have to figure out how to call a stored procedure from it instead of embedding SQL.

Comment: Thank you very much, Aaron!!  I took your ^^^ suggestions and upgraded my code.  I greatly appreciate that you took time to do this for me - I learn best when I can see an example of something that I understand... thank you!!